# Is this type of curtain track solid enough for children?

Tags: curtain-rail

I'm considering purchasing this [plastic curtain track](http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/6234791.htm#pdpFullProductInformation). However I am concerned regarding the robustness of the hooks which attach the track to the wall. These look a bit like this one: 
[image: picture]

But what if my daughter plays with the curtain? Will it not easily break?

Comment: You may want to ask the question "*How can I get my daughter to not play with the curtains?*" on [Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/). Or get heavy duty curtain track, and make sure you attach it to studs using lag bolts.

Comment: I gotta say, the way the question reads it sounds something like "Is this curtain track solid enough for (my) children (to climb the curtains on)?" I don't tend to find my kid interested in curtains at all, but if you really can't keep yours away from them perhaps try the compression bars until they're older, those are harmless when they come down.